# Change src on selection

Tags: attributes, src

I want to change the src attribute of image according to the selection of drop list menu. For example, the droplist contains "Peter, Henry, David", the image will show different images accordingly to the name (something like peter.png, henry.png, david.png, or 1.png, 2.png, 3.png)
So here is what I did. However, it didn't work. I don't know what I missed here.

```
<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="Peter">Peter</option> 
<option value="Henry">Henry</option> 
<option value="David">David</option> 
</select>

 <img src="default.png" id="imageholder" alt="imageholder" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#name").change(function() { 
        var nameholder= $("#name").val(); 
        $('#imageholder').attr('src', nameholder + ".png" ); 
        });   
    })  
    </script>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo when you input into SO but you are missing the `<` on your `script` tag: `script type="text/javascript">`. That will definitely cause an error. Make it `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: it was a typo, I do have the < on my code

Comment: I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tEgQz/1/ . My only guess is an issue of case-sensitivity; you are seeking for `David.png` when your file is actually named `david.png`. Also, can you expand on what you mean by "it ddidn't work"

Comment: Yeah, the code works fine. You just need to adjust your filenames.

Comment: Here it with the String.toLowerCase() method http://jsfiddle.net/tEgQz/2/

Comment: For readability, please be consistent with single and double quotes.

Comment: thank you all, I found out the reason why it didn't work. I used the older version of jquery lib.